# Use group by and having with count in sql

Tags: sql, database

Here is my table

```
-----------------
| id | uid| pass|
|----------------
| 1  | 1  | pass|
| 2  | 2  | fail|
| 3  | 1  | pass|
| 4  | 2  | pass|
| 5  | 3  | pass|
-----------------
```

Here is what I want

```
-----------------
| id | uid| pass|
|----------------
| 1  | 1  | pass|
| 3  | 1  | pass|
-----------------
```

I have tried with this sql

```
select id,uid,pass
from user
group by id,uid,pass
having count(uid)=2 and pass = pass
```

This SQL doesn't work. I have already looked at all questions related to my problem.
but I couldn't have found what I want.

Please help me out. any feedback please

Comment: Can you explain why you want those rows returned? Like "I'm looking for records where the user.id shows up twice in the table and both records have the same `pass` column value"? It's not clear.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the rows for uids with two passes:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, count(*) over (partition by uid) as cnt
      from user u
      where pass = 'pass'
     ) u
where cnt = 2;
```

If you also want them to have no fails, then use conditional logic:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, 
             sum(case when pass = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by uid) as cnt_pass,
             sum(case when pass = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by uid) as cnt_fail
      from user u
      where pass = 'pass'
     ) u
where cnt_pass = 2 and cnt_fail = 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c50ad80764ceb33230bc389350affe93) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @hellomynameis . . . A typo.

Comment: @hellomynameis . . . The code is fine (except that `user` might be a reserved word in your database).  I've included a db<>fiddle illustrating that both work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
select uid
from user u
group by uid
having count(id) = 2 and min(pass) = max(pass) and min(pass) = 'pass';
```

If you want full row then use window function :

```
select u.*
from (select u.*, 
             max(case when pass = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by uid) as fail_flag,
             count(*) over (partition by uid) as cnt
      from user u
     ) u
where fail_flag = 0 and cnt > 1;
```

Comment: @hellomynameis. . . Corrected.

Comment: hm.. having syntax error and still not working... thank you anyway!

Comment: The first will not work if the OP wants uid values included for anything with two "pass" and any number of "fail"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to identify the uid that meet the criteria...

```
SELECT uid FROM `user` WHERE pass = 'pass' GROUP BY uid HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Then you use that to get the records that contributed to that....

```
SELECT u.*
FROM `user` AS u
WHERE u.pass = 'pass' 
   AND u.uid IN (thequeryabove)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select uid, count(pass) as "Passing Results"
from user
where pass = 'pass'
group by uid
```

Comment: Had mixed up uid and id. Presuming ID is instance ID and UID is userid. Try what it currently has above.